# How do I calculate the CPU usage of a container in percent?

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I'd like to know the CPU usage of my containers in relation to their CPU resource limits. I can get the **CPU resource limits** like so

```
avg_over_time(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{container="udf",namespace="rwc-g1hhgcv4t0f0k8cr19qbl8coqk-test", unit="core"}[1m]) * 60
```

[Docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/pod-metrics.md) for `kube_pod_container_resource_limits`

> The number of requested limit resource by a container. It is recommended to use the kube_pod_resource_limits metric exposed by kube-scheduler instead, as it is more precise.

For some reason `kube_pod_resource_limits` is unavailable. I am using `* 60`, since there are 60 seconds in a minute. You can see here that all the different containers all have 1 core available, resulting in 60 seconds per minute max CPU time. This may change in the future.

[image]

Now to the actual **CPU usage**: I am using `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`. Total is the sum of user and system time spend on the CPU. I am again averaging over 1 minute.

```
avg_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container="some-container",namespace="some-ns"}[1m])
```

The CPU usage of the different containers.

[image]

**Why can I not calc the percentage now?** I would like to do below, to calculate the CPU usage percentage. Time spend in the CPU in relation to what is available. Per minute. If I do that I get "no data"

```
avg_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container="some-container",namespace="some-ns"}[1m]) / (avg_over_time(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{container="udf",namespace="rwc-g1hhgcv4t0f0k8cr19qbl8coqk-test", unit="core"}[1m]) * 60) * 100
```